# QuickBooks QBSDK "Could not find or create an instance of QuickBooks using InstanceFinder"

Tags: quickbooks

I have seen a couple of posts on here regarding this error.
However, I have not seen a solution that works for our situation.

I have a QuickBooks "Integrated Application" written in C# using QBFC 13.0. It is installed and working correctly on my test systems, but can't get it to work on the production Server.

We are using QuickBooks 2014 and running it on a Server 2008 machine.

I have tried:
01. Updating QB

2. Made sure the App is built for Target x86 only.
3. Keep QuickBooks running is Un-checked in the General Preferences.
4. QuickBooks and the application are running at the same user level
5. Path and Filename are correct.
6. Gave Full permissions to everyone for the files and folders
7. Tried a 3rd party software which is producing the same error
8. Tried running as different users. With and without admin

Here is part of the QBSDK log message:

```
Begin Session started...
OS: Microsoft Standard Edition (build 9200), 64-bit
Current Process is not elevated
Current User is in AdminGroup
Current Process is not ran as Admin
Current Process Integrity Level : 2000
Not in-proc request.
File info: "pathofQBFile.qbw", v24.0R8 (2403), wholesale, standard_stratum
Getting an instance of pRunningInfo
GetmajorVersion
GetReleaseNumber
Getflavor
GetdataFileVersion
There is a running version of QuickBooks: v24.0R8 (2403), wholesale, standard_stratum
Starting QuickBooks (no launch): Install info: v24.0R8 (2403), wholesale, standard_stratum
Performing QB Launch Retries
Check QB process ID before calling instance finder to find it.
Process Found -> 15996 for Current User -> username
QBW32.exe Proc Id: 15996
Getting the IUnknown COM instance of QB
Obtained the IUnknown COM instance of QB without an exception
QuickBooks launch succeeded.
Could not find or create an instance of QuickBooks using InstanceFinder
Connection closed by app named 'Quickbooks API Syncs'
========== Ended Connection ==========
```

Answer (score 1):

Update

Using Process monitor, I found out that the application had no rights to some registry keys. After fixing all of the registry security settings, the Application is working now.